# How to update an Entity and many to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried to update an Entity of this way but I get errors about Keys.

I want to know how can I get the relations of the Entity Product in the parameter or inside the method. I think is the solution.

```
public static bool UpdateProduct( Product myProduct , int[] newCategoriesID )
{
    bool operation = false;
    using ( var ctx = new TestContext() )
    {
        ctx.Entry( myProduct ).State = EntityState.Modified;
        var newCategories = ctx.Categories.Where( c => newCategoriesID.Contains( c.id ) ).ToList();
        myProduct.Categories.Clear();
        foreach ( var newCat in newCategories )
        {
            myProduct.Categories.Add( newCat );
        }
        ctx.Products.Attach( myProduct );
        int countChanges = ctx.SaveChanges();
        if ( countChanges > 0 )
        {
            operation = true;
        }
    }
    return operation;
}
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and the last version of Entity Framework.

Comment: What specific errors are you getting?

Comment: When I try to save changes there's a problem about the key in the database. The error is: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ProductCategory'. You can not insert duplicate in the 'dbo.ProductCategory' object key. The value of the duplicate key is (1004, 2). "
 I think, the parameter myProduct hasn't the relation because when I was testing with a console application it works when I use for example "Product myproduct= ctx.Products.Include("Categories").SingleOrDefault(x=>x.id == 1002);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works but I don't know if it's well

```
public static bool UpdateProduct( Product myProduct , int[] newCategoriesID )
    {
        bool operation = false;
        using ( var ctx = new TestContext() )
        {
//find the product in the database and include the relation
            var existeproduct = ctx.Products.Include("Categories").SingleOrDefault(x=>x.id == myProduct.id);
// Change the current and original values by copying the values from other objects
            ctx.Entry( existeproduct ).CurrentValues.SetValues(myProduct);
            ctx.Entry( existeproduct ).State = EntityState.Modified;
            var newCategories = ctx.Categories.Where( c => newCategoriesID.Contains( c.id ) ).ToList();
            existeproduct.Categories.Clear();
            foreach ( var newCat in newCategories )
            {
                existeproduct.Categories.Add( newCat );
            }
            int countChanges = ctx.SaveChanges();
            if ( countChanges > 0 )
            {
                operation = true;
            }
        }
        return operation;
    }
```